# How can I get specific date in a year?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I wanna make a lesson scheduler. For example all friday's lessons same and should show on scheduler. How can I get all friday's date in a year? 
I have some datafield for this ;

```
-Dayofweek  int
-Starthour  int
-finishhour int
```

Answer (score 0):

just like this，notice 365 may be 366. you can judge it..

```
 DateTime dt=DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-01-01"));
   for (int i = 0; i < 365;i++ )
   {
       if (dt.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek==DayOfWeek.Friday)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(dt.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString());
       }

   }
```

Comment: Surely it's more efficient to find the first friday in the year, and then `i += 7`.

Answer (score 0):

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetAllDaysInYearByDayOfWeek(int year, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    var startOfYear = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    var firstMatchingDate = startOfYear.AddDays((dayOfWeek - startOfYear.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7);
    for (var dt = firstMatchingDate; dt.Year == year; dt = dt.AddDays(7))
        yield return dt;
}
```

For example:

```
var fridays = GetAllDaysInYearByDayOfWeek(2013, DayOfWeek.Friday);
foreach (DateTime day in fridays)
    Console.WriteLine(day.ToShortDateString());
```

Results:

```
01/04/2013
01/11/2013
01/18/2013
...
12/13/2013
12/20/2013
12/27/2013
```